# I can't open my associated Stack Overflow account

Tags: support, stack-overflow, login

I logged out of my Stack Overflow account a few days ago. But once I logged out I couldn't log back in. I even tried to recover the password but when I entered the email it created me a new id. Can somebody please help me? I am logged into all other accounts except Stack Overflow.

Comment: So do you want to merge your all accounts ?

Comment: @lucifier no i forgot my SO password.I want to log back in to that account

Answer (score 4):

Drop us a line via the "contact us" link at the bottom of any page. If you have the URLs for your profiles, use the "Merge user profiles" path. Otherwise, go with "other" and give us any information you can to identify your accounts - emails addresses used are usually best.

We can go from there.